# yud ha'heh -official name

Tags: names, aleph-bet-letters, safrus

What is the official name of the yud in the heh, and tet in the tuf -
do we say simply yud ha'heh and tet ha'tuf (assuming tuf is vav with a roof, followed by backward-facing script-tet) ? Also, is there a relation between
vav and tet?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with _safrus_ (how to write a Torah scroll and the like), and am not picturing how a _tav_ can be construed as a _vav_ followed by a backward _tes_.

Comment: if anything, a Tuf is a Reish and a Vav.

Comment: @msh210 You must have keen insight! (Maybe that's why you're a moderator :-) How did you determine that this was a safrut question from just the question itself, or did you view the tags to figure that out? I recommend editing this so that it is clear up front that this is related to safrut. I had no clue what the OP was saying.

Answer (score 1):

**The Yud in the Heh - ה**

<sup>In Hilchot Safrus we consider the ה to be made up of a ד and an upside down י</sup>

In [סימן לב - סדר כתיבת התפלין](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_3.html#HtmpReportNum0007_L2) sometimes it's called *the inside leg of the Heh* other times it's called *the leg of the Heh*

> נִקַּב **רֶגֶל פְּנִימִי שֶׁל הֵ '' א** אֲפִלּוּ לֹא נִשְׁאַר מִמֶּנּוּ אֶלָּא כָּל שֶׁהוּא כָּשֵׁר לְהָרֹא''שׁ
>
> אִם נָגְעוּ **רַגְלֵי הַהֵ '' א** וְהַקּוֹ''ף  בַּגַּג יִגְרֹר הָרֶגֶל וְיַחֲזֹר וְיִכְתְּבֶנּוּ

**The Tet in the Tuf - ת**

In Hilchot Safrus we consider the ת to be made up of a ר and an upside down ו - but it would be referred to as the left leg of the Tuf. Can't find an easy reference to that now.

Comment: The left leg of the ת: _Mishnas Sof'rim_ (_MB_), at least, calls it that.

Comment: assuming quf is formed with a cuf, then it makes sense that tuf is formed with tet, nu?

Comment: @sam, I don't follow the logic - sounds like a joke. Maybe it is. Besides a quf ק is not formed with a cuf כ, but I can see why you think so. (A _legless_ quf would not be a Kosher cuf, as the roof and floor of the cuf כ have to be the same length.) But how you get from ט Tet to Tuf ת is a mystery.